# Не передаются данные PUT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Добрый день и заранее спасибо.

Я пытаюсь отправить PUT запрос на сервер Node.js с React

База данных MongoDB

Вот функция получения с input значения, и в comment оно приходит

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(comment);
  dispatch(updateUserFinanceInfo({
    comment
  }));
  clearInput();
};
```

Вот компонент в React

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="">
  {commentDirty && commentError && (
    <span
      style={{
        color: "red",
        fontSize: 15,
        paddingTop: 4,
      }}
    >
      {errorSymbol}{" "}
    </span>
  )}
  <p>Write new Comment:</p>
  <input
    onBlur={handleChange}
    onChange={commentHandler}
    type="text"
    value={comment}
    placeholder="Comment"
  />
  <button type="submit">
    <span>Save</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Вот так я отправляю запрос:

```js
export const updateUserFinanceInfo = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/profile/update",
  async (_, {
    credentials,
    rejectWithValue
  }) => {
    try {
      const {
        data
      } = await axios.put(
        "auth/profile/update",
        credentials
      );
      console.log("data", data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Я проверил работоспособность запроса через Postman, данные отправляются, а с функции React нет и я не пойму в чем ошибка

Comment: "auth/profile/update" -> ` "/auth/profile/update"` ?

Comment: @nörbörnën Нет это не поможет поскольку ссылку я объявляю вот так: http://localhost:1594/api / и к тому же я вижу что на сервер запрос отправляется, но я получаю пустой req.body, функция почему-то не получает данные

Comment: Если сервер ваш, поставьте там логирование и посмотрите, что происходит, если вы говорите, что запрос отправляется и данные приходят(пустые)

Comment: @SwaD Если отправлять данные на сервер напрямую то данные приходят не пустые, они пустые с функции React

Comment: Они не передаются в credentials

Comment: переменные переназовите, у вас две credentials

Comment: Попробуйте в запрос добавить header и вписать туда `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо!, обратил на это внимание, но проблема была в другом, я не правильно получал данные, было: async (_, { credentials, rejectWithValue }), стало: async (credentials, { rejectWithValue })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в неправильных получаемых данных:

```
async (credentials, { rejectWithValue })
```